# Google eclipse plugin's initial App Engine skeleton app does nothing but 404 on localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

Ok, so I use the GPE to create a new web project employing GAE but not GWT.  Then, I right-click the project and do Run As -> (Google) Web application.  Server starts up without error and tells me to visit: http://localhost:8888/.

When I visit this url, I'm served a 404 error instead of the index.html page that the project is configured to display right out of the box!  Does this not fail for everybody else?!

Note that when I deploy this app to GAE, it operates just fine.

I'm Running:

- Win XP SP3
- Eclipse Helios
- Google App Engine Java SDK 1.3.7
- Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6

Help!  Please!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a caching issue.